# Python function not appending last value to list

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I'm writing a function that generates a list of n booleans. Suppose the list returned is `[True, False, True, True, False]`. I need to produce  list based on the booleans that identifies streaks of the same values. So the result in this case would be `[1, 1, 2, 1]`. For some reason, my code does not include the last run. In the provided example, mine would produce `[1, 1, 2]`. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

```
#Makes list of bools
def bools(p, n):
    return (rand(n) < p)

#Makes list that counts successive values
def succession(p, n):
    run = bools(p, n)
    print run

    successionlist = []

    counter = 1
    for j in range(1, n):
        if run[j] == run[j - 1]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            successionlist.append(counter)
            print successionlist
            counter = 1
```

Comment: Aside: you might be interested in [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby); your code would become something like `[sum(1 for _ in g) for k,g in groupby(run)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you append only when you get a different value. you need to append in the end again

```
successionlist = []

counter = 1
for j in range(1, n):
    if run[j] == run[j - 1]:
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        successionlist.append(counter)
        print successionlist
        counter = 1
successionlist.append(counter)
print successionlist
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `succesionlist.append(counter)` to the body oft your function, right *after* the `for` loop. The reason for this is that you only ever append the counter to the list when the value changes from `True` to `False` or vice versa, but the value will never change after the last value, even though you currently have a count of elements that is needed for the final result. Subsequently you always need to append the counter after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you only append a value to the succession list if the two last elements differ. So if your input array ends with a sequence, the loop runs through and just increments the counter without adding it to the result list. I would try checking for the situation when you are at the last element and its the same as the one before explicitly.

```
successionlist = []

counter = 1
for j in range(1, n):
    if run[j] == run[j - 1]:
        counter = counter + 1
        # Check for the last element
        if j == n-1:
            successionlist.append(counter)
    else:
        successionlist.append(counter)
        print successionlist
        counter = 1

print successionlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
list=[True, False, True, True, False]


def succession(list):
    result = []
    saved = -1

    for value in list:
        int_value = int(value)
        if int_value == saved:
            result[-1] += 1
        else:
            result.append(1)
        saved = int_value
    return result



print succession(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest might be to append at the beginning rather than the end of the succession:

```
#Makes list of bools
def bools(p, n):
    return (rand(n) < p)

#Makes list that counts successive values
def succession(p, n):
    run = bools(p, n)
    print run

    lastvalue = None
    successionlist = []
    for item in run:
        if item is not lastvalue:
            lastvalue = item
            successionlist.append(0)
        successionlist[-1] += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
counter = 1
for j in range(1, n):
    if run[j] == run[j - 1]:
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        successionlist.append(counter)
        print successionlist
        counter = 1
else:
    successionlist.append(counter)
```

Comment: The `else` after the `for` loop is superfluous.